# SQL query for counting combinations and including entries that don't exist

Tags: sql, oracle, count

This is a simplified version of the table I am dealing with which is Orders

```
+-------------------+------------------+---------------+
| Order_Base_Number | Order_Lot_Number | Other Cols... |
+-------------------+------------------+---------------+
|                 1 |                3 |               |
|                 1 |                3 |               |
|                 1 |                4 |               |
|                 1 |                4 |               |
|                 1 |                4 |               |
|                 1 |                5 |               |
|                 2 |                3 |               |
|                 2 |                5 |               |
|                 2 |                9 |               |
|                 2 |               10 |               |
+-------------------+------------------+---------------+
```

What I want to do is to get a count for the unique entries base on Base and Lot numbers. I have two set of numbers, one is a set of Base numbers and the other is a set of Lot numbers.
for example, lets say the two sets are Base In (1,2,3) and Lot is in (3,4,20).

I am looking for an SQL query that can return all the possible combination of (Base,Lot) from the two sets with a count that shows how many times the combination was found in the table. My problem is that I want to include all the possible combinations and if a combination is not in the Orders table, I want the count to show zero. So, the output I am looking for is something like this.

```
+------+-----+-----------+
| Base | Lot | Frequency |
+------+-----+-----------+
|    1 |   3 |    2      |
|    1 |   4 |    3      |
|    1 |  20 |    0      |
|    2 |   3 |    1      |
|    2 |   4 |    0      |
|    2 |  20 |    0      |
|    3 |   3 |    0      |
|    3 |   4 |    0      |
|    3 |  20 |    0      |
+------+-----+-----------+
```

I tried a lot of queries but never got close to this and not even sure if it can be done. Right now I am figuring out the combinations on the client side and hence I am performing too many queries to get the frequencies.

Comment: Which platform are you using, SQL Server, Oracle, DB2....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the clearest way is to start with the lists as CTEs:

```
with bases as (
    select 1 as base from dual union all
    select 2 as base from dual union all
    select 3 as base from dual
   ),
     lots as (
    select 3 as lot from dual union all
    select 4 as lot from dual union all
    select 20 as lot from dual
   )
select b.base, l.lot, count(Order_Base_Number) as Frequency
from bases b cross join lots l left outer join
     Orders o
     on o.base = b.base and o.lot = l.lot
group by b.base, l.lot
```

Note that this makes the `cross join` explicit, purposely not using the `,` for a Cartesian product.

The first part of this query could also be written as something like the following (assuming that each base and lot has at least one record in the table):

```
with bases as (
     select distinct base
     from Orders  -- or some other table, perhaps Orders ?
     where base in (1, 2, 3)
    ),
     select distinct lot
     from Orders  -- or some other table, perhaps Lots ?
     where lot in (3, 4, 20)
    )
. . .
```

This is more succinct, but might result in a less efficient query.

Comment: I was under the impression that SQL Server has CTE but Oracle does not.

Comment: @Hogan . . . Oracle might call them something else, but it does support the `with` syntax.  You can test it on SQLFiddle (www.sqlfiddle.com).

Comment: very cool @GordonLinoff -- I'll remember this next time I'm answering a Oracle question.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon. This is exactly what I wanted. However, I think the second part won't work because none existing base ids or lot ids in the Orders table will not show up in the resulted tables 'Bases' and 'Lots'.

Answer (score 0):

What you need in the innermost subquery is called `CROSS JOIN`, which gets cartesian products (all possible combinations) of records. That's what you get when you have neither `JOIN..ON condition` nor `WHERE`:

```
SELECT Base.Id as baseid, Lot.Id as lotid FROM Bases, Lots
```

Now put it into subquery and `LEFT JOIN` to the rest of your stuff:

```
SELECT ... FROM 
   (SELECT Base.Id as baseid, Lot.Id as lotid 
           FROM Bases, Lots) baseslots
   LEFT JOIN Orders ON Order_Base_Number = baseid, 
             Order_Lot_Number = lotid ....
```

With this `LEFT JOIN`, you'll get NULL for nonexistent combinations. Use `COALESCE` (or something like this) to turn them into 0.

Comment: Please don't use the implicit-join syntax, always explicitly state your joins.  Also, this presumes that `Bases` and `Lots` exist, which may not be the case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Oracle to test it but this is what I would do:

```
CREATE TABLE pairs AS
(
SELECT DISTINCT Base.Order_Base_Number, Lot.Order_Lot_Number 
FROM ORDERS Base
CROSS JOIN ORDERS Lot
);

CREATE TABLE counts AS
(
SELECT Order_Base_Number, Order_Lot_Number, Count(*) AS C
FROM ORDERS 
GROUP BY Order_Base_Number, Order_Lot_Number
);

SELECT P.Order_Base_Number, P.Order_Lot_Number, COALESCE(C.C,0) AS [Count]
FROM Pairs P
LEFT JOIN counts C ON P.Order_Base_Number = C.Order_Base_Number 
             AND P.Order_Lot_Number = C.Order_Lot_Number
```

Comment: You probably don't need an actual table - CTEs as Gordon uses should be fine.  Also, `pairs` presumes that all possible combinations are represented, which I doubt is guaranteed; if you'll note in the OPs question, he mentions he wants results when the given combination may not exist.  And given that you are using an `INNER JOIN` in your final query, `COALESCE(C.C, 0)` is pointless.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse - I did not know Oracle supported CTE's (see my comments to Gordon's post.)  A CROSS JOIN will make all possible combinations (try it.)  You are right about the last join, fixed.

Comment: ... Seriously, I somehow missed that was a `CROSS JOIN`, and only thought it had a `FROM` clause.  I don't know what came over me...

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse - Yeah, clearly CTE + Cross Join is the best answer to this question, we need a mutant merging of my and Gordon's answer.